# Socket.io 1.2.1 and Unity using .net

Tags: c#, .net, node.js, unity-game-engine, socket.io

I currently develop an application game with unity. I want to use socket.io for communication with a node server. I found socketio4net but it's only for old version of socket.io.
I have to use socket.io because I use this server to communicate with browser. 
When I try to connect using the old version I have:

> Error iniatlising handsake with //localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the BestHTTP (https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/10765) asset with great success in the past and they just added official support for Socket.IO:

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/best-http-released.200006/page-6#post-1937191