# I can not connect socket io with windows phone 8.1 C#

Tags: javascript, c#, websocket, socket.io, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to develop a chat application in windows phone 8.1 (am not using the silverlight version), I created a server with Node.JS and with socket.io. But am not able to connect to the server from my windows phone 8.1 App. I tried using both SocketIO4Net and SockeIOClientDotNet. Both where not connecting. Is there any alternative options? Which is the best way to do it?

Comment: Did u set the right application permissions?

Comment: It is almost impossible to make any suggestions concerning your problem without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

You use socket.io 1.0 or later, and SocketIO4Net and SockeIOClientDotNet only work for
0.9.*

I currently looking for other library for that.

[Socket.io 1.2.1 and Unity using .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760085/socket-io-1-2-1-and-unity-using-net)